# Check if file exists in different directory and respond accordingly

Tags: batch-file

I want to send a undefined number of files to ftp server on a given time of day. After the files are sent I want to save them to another directory and them erase them from the previous directory. Something like this:

```
ftp -i -s:SendFile.scr serverIp
copy log*.txt C:\Reg\Archives
del log*.txt
```

This .bat works, however it does not take into account if the file to be copied already exists in the `Archives` directory, the original is erased and I need it both files to be appended. So, I've written:

```
ftp -i -s:SendFile.scr 213.13.123.68
IF EXIST C:\Users\Miguel\Archives\tes*.txt
(
    copy /a C:\Users\Miguel\Archives\tes*.txt +  C:\Users\Miguel\tes*.txt  C:\Users\Miguel\Archives\tes*.txt
)
ELSE 
(
    copy tes*.txt  C:\Users\Miguel\Archives
)
del tes*.txt
```

However this does not work, I've also thought to cd directory and to do it from there but I can't seem to think the proper way to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I notice 2 problems immediately.  #1, in your `if exist` block, your `copy` command's destination includes a wildcard.  Did you mean to concatenate all the text files into one new file?  If so, specify a filename without an asterisk.  If not, then get rid of the `+` sign and just set the destination as a directory.  #2: When using `del` with a wildcard, add the `/q` switch to suppress the confirmation question.

Comment: No, I don't mean to put them all together, I didn't explain well on that one. I have several `tes` files, eg. test2014335.txt, test2014336.txt and if 1 of them already exists in the destination folder, only then I want to append the file. If it doesn't exist, then copy it. So if I remove the `+` how do I append?

Comment: Append *what* file though?  Right now you're trying to concatenate all `%userprofile%\Archives\tes*.txt` and all `%userprofile%\tes*.txt` into a single file with an impossible filename.  `*` cannot be part of a filename.  Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have a routine that creates a file per day. This file is appended every minute. And twice a day I want to make the transfer from that machine to my server. So at midnight I'll have the same file name, eg. test2014336.txt in my client and in my server. If the file is not in the server (1st time it's sending) then just copy it. If its already there, I don't want to miss on the previous information, so I need to append the rest of information.

Comment: I understand that I cannot use a wildcard, but since there is an undefined number of files, normally its 1, but it can be more, I'm not able to see how I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for appending or just copying the text file depending on existence of the text file with same name in archives directory.

```
@echo off
for %%I in ("%USERPROFILE%\tes*.txt") do (
    if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Archives\%%~nxI" (
        copy /B "%USERPROFILE%\Archives\%%~nxI" + "%%~I" "%USERPROFILE%\Archives\%%~nxI" >nul
    ) else (
        copy /B "%%~I" "%USERPROFILE%\Archives" >nul
    )
    del /Q "%%~I"
)
```

The command [FOR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) is used here to process all tes*.txt files in the directory file by file. You can get help on command **FOR** also be entering `for /?` or `help for` in a command prompt window.

`%%~I` references entire file name with full path of the file to process next without double quotes.

`%%~nxI` references just file name and file extension without path of the file to process.

`/B` (binary file) is used instead of `/A` (ASCII file) to avoid appending `^Z` to end of destination file on append. `^Z` is a byte with hexadecimal value 1A and means end of file.

**Note:**

Command **copy** used to append a file to another file does never check if the existing file ends with a line terminator (carriage return + line-feed) before appending the other file even on usage of `/A`. So please verify that your tes*.txt files always end with a line terminator as otherwise it could happen that last line of existing file in archives directory is merged together with first line of the source file on append.

Example:

`%USERPROFILE%\Archives\test2014336.txt` ends with `No error.` and has no line termination at end of file.

`%USERPROFILE%\test2014336.txt` starts with `Results for ...` and has no line termination at beginning of file.

The file `%USERPROFILE%\Archives\test2014336.txt` would contain in this case after append

```
No error.Results for ...
```

instead of

```
No error.
Results for ...
```

Comment: You are my hero. Thanks!